# Laravel validation not working after submit

Tags: laravel

This did not show the errors after submit

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cars;
use App\Images;
use DB;

$this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required|min:3',
        'specifications'=>'required|min:10'
]);
```

Inserting values into the database.I want to validate on submitting the form

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request->all(),[
        'name'=>'required|min:3',
        'specifications'=>'required|min:10'
    ]);

    $cars = New Cars;
    $cars->name = $request->name;
    $cars->specifications = $request->specifications;
    $cars->price = $request->price;
    $cars->model_id = $request->model_id;
    $cars->year = $request->year;
    $cars->milage = $request->milage;
    if($cars->save()) {
        $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    }
    return redirect('home');
}
```

I displayed errors like this, but not working for me

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <p>{{ $error }}</p>
        @endforeach
      </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `->all()` here to provide all input value in to validate

```
$this->validate($request->all(),[
```

Or you can try like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    // The blog post is valid...
}
```

And display error as

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Share complete controller code and how you put value in `$errors` ?

Comment: Shared please check once

Comment: try by using  `$request->validate([`  instead `$this->validate($request->all(),[` as doc [says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validation-quickstart)

Comment: @BhaskararaoGummidi : try this https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#manually-creating-validators

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code on your controller method.

`return back()->withErrors()->withInput()`

you can also access old input value with `old(field_name)`

Answer (score 0):

first, edit your method like this :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cars;
use App\Images;
use DB;
use Validator;
```

and inside this method please edit your redirect route and make sure your redirect url, redirect you in the page that had the error message:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'name'=>'required|min:3',
                    'specifications'=>'required|min:10'
                ]);
                if ($validator->fails()) {
                    return redirect(route('make your route here '))
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
                }

            $cars = New Cars;
            $cars->name = $request->name;
            $cars->specifications = $request->specifications;
            $cars->price = $request->price;
            $cars->model_id = $request->model_id;
            $cars->year = $request->year;
            $cars->milage = $request->milage;
            if($cars->save()) {
                $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
            }
            return redirect('home');
    }
```

and for displaying error messages inside your blade template make this :

```
@if(!empty($errors))
    @if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger"> 
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
@endif
```